# Spacy lemma different results from 'English' class and en_core_web_sm

Tags: python, spacy

I am wondering why I get different lemmatization results from these two language models: spacy.lang.en.English and en_core_web_sm.

According to the documentation, when loading the en_core_web_sm model this should tell spacy to use the language "en" and initialize spacy.lang.en.English so I don't understand why the lemmatization rules change. How can I get the lemmas from the English model but the tag and POS from en_core_web_sm?

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
doc = nlp('nonlinearities')
print('English nlp: ', [(token.lemma_, token.lemma, token.tag_, token.pos_) for token in doc])

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable = ['ner'])
doc = nlp('nonlinearities')
print('loaded model nlp: ', [(token.lemma_, token.lemma, token.tag_, token.pos_) for token in doc])
```

Here is the output:

```
English nlp:  [('nonlinearity', 3011504801575762058, '', '')]
loaded model nlp:  [('nonlinearitie', 2964900603636025371, 'NNS', 'NOUN')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out `spacy.lang.en.English` and `en_core_web_sm` are two different models. These two models might POS tag a word differently.  And since the lemma of a word also depends on its POS tag, two models might return different lemmatizations.

To use lemma from `English` and POS from `en_core_web_sm`

```
nlp = English()
sentence = 'nonlinearities is none'
doc1 = nlp(sentence)
print('English nlp: ', [(token.lemma_, token.lemma, token.tag_, token.pos_) for token in doc1])

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable = ['ner'])
doc2 = nlp(sentence)
print('loaded model nlp: ', [(token.lemma_, token.lemma, token.tag_, token.pos_) for token in doc2])

print('Mixed nlp: ', [(doc1[i].lemma_, doc1[i].lemma, token.tag_, token.pos_) for i, token in enumerate(doc2)])
doc2 = nlp('nonlinearities is none')
print('loaded model nlp: ', [(token.lemma_, token.lemma, token.tag_, token.pos_) for token in doc2])

print('Mixed nlp: ', [(doc1[i].lemma_, doc1[i].lemma, token.tag_, token.pos_) for i, token in enumerate(doc2)])
```

Comment: To add to this, `spacy.lang.en.English` is the base language class shipped with the library and only includes the language data. There's no statistical model (because you're not loading in any data), so there are also no part-of-speech tags. The `en_core_web_sm` package you load in ships with weights for the statistical components, including the part-of-speech tagger.